# Start an action when an AsyncTask has finished

Tags: android, android-listview, android-asynctask

I've got an adapter for a `ListView`, inside of it, I run an `AsyncTask` which download a file. I want to update the `ListView` when my download has finished.

I think I should use : `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` when the `AsyncTask.getStatus()` is `FINISHED`, but I did not figured out how to do that, it always goes through the "if" because the state of `getStatus()` is `RUNNING`.

```
final DownloadTask async = new DownloadTask(context, position, list);

button1.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (button1.getText() == "Télécharger") {
            button1.setEnabled(false);
            button1.setText("Téléchargement en cours ...");
            async.execute(0);
            // if(async.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED){
            //  // Try to refresh the view here
            //   Log.i("TAG","FINISHED !");
            // }
        } else if (button1.getText() == "Lire") {
            Intent i1 = new Intent(context, WebActivity.class);
            i1.putExtra("position", position);
            context.startActivity(i1);
        }
    }

});
```

Comment: use onPostExecute. is list  your ListView?

Comment: the third paramter of your AsyncTask is the ListView?

Comment: "list" is a json stocked inside a string, it contain the url of the file to download.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The AsyncTask comes with the [`onPostExecute(Result)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPostExecute%28Result%29), which runs on the UI Thread and provides exactly the functionality you'll need.

Comment: But the AsyncTask is in another class, it will not reload the view if run the notifyDataSetChanged.

Comment: OK if I move the AsyncTask inside my Adapter class, I can run the notifyDataSetChanged, thanks !